# The data model cannot be executed because of an error, please contact the administrator

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

I have a data sets that contains a columns which the parameters is by name, date and number. But everytime I view the data there's a error said `The data model cannot be executed because of an error, please contact the administrator.` But it only show the message but didn't show the details of the error. I also have a list of values because I set the parameter type of my parameters for `name` and `number` as a `menu` which is the result 
that will return for the `number` is based on the `name` because if I didn't base it on the name it will return a 100+ values which is not okay to my user.

My query for my data set for example is,

```
select a.name, a.date, a.type_name, b.number, c.address
from details1 a, details2 b, details3 c
where
a.id = b.id
and b.id = c.id
and a.name = :name
and a.date between :start_date and :end_date
and b.number = :number
```

Query of List of Values for `name`

```
select a.name from details1 a
where a.type_name = 'person'
```

Query of List of Values for `num`

```
select b.number
from details1 a, details2 b
where 1=1
and a.id = b.id
and a.name = :name
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know BI Publisher, but - as far as Oracle is concerned, column name can **not** be `number`. It is reserved word for a datatype:

```
SQL> create table test (number number);
create table test (number number)
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Your query uses such a column:

```
select b.number ...
```

which can't work, unless someone created such a table by enclosing column name into double quotes, e.g.

```
SQL> create table test ("number" number);

Table created.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------
 number                                             NUMBER

SQL>
```

However, you'll have to specify such a column name using double quotes every time, paying attention to letter case (meaning: if column was created as "NumBER", you have to reference it exactly that way. "numBER" or "NUMber" or "nUmBeR" or "number" or "NUMBER" won't work). A few examples:

```
SQL> insert into test (number) values (1);
insert into test (number) values (1)
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword


SQL> insert into test ("NUMber") values (1);
insert into test ("NUMber") values (1)
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NUMber": invalid identifier


SQL> insert into test ("NUMBER") values (1);
insert into test ("NUMBER") values (1)
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NUMBER": invalid identifier


SQL> insert into test ("number") values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> select t."number" from test t;

    number
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Therefore, I'd suggest you to check table description and try with what you see; maybe it is as simple as

```
select b."number" ...
```

If that's the case, it is more than obvious that doing something because you *can* do it doesn't mean that you *should* do it. Avoid such things, never enclose Oracle object names into double quotes, use defaults.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry but the column name number is just for example. Actually it has a name that oracle provided I just use the term "number" as sample. Btw, thanks for this.

Comment: whatever you do, do NOT create a column called "number" or "table" or any other reserved word. it will haunt you forever